# ReactJS + Redux | Collect data from individual components to a higher level and make a request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I have in my React/Redux App, a selection of components. Each component is basically a Form. I am using `Formik` for the form, no problem there.

We have the following Components:
1. Input text and text area.
2. Multi-select with autocomplete and dropdown.
3. Checkbox Table with a few options

The actual components aren't finished but my problem isn't with them. The problem is the following:

We have 2 screen implementation for the previous components. One is a read/edit screen. The other one is a create screen wizard style, with 3 steps.

**THE PROBLEM**
There are validation steps and data fetching in all steps. That means, that I want to make a call before going to the next step to validate stuff with the server. On the other hand, I want to update or create items on the server on a single call.

My approach would be to actually dispatch a call for validation, on each step, and at that time if the response is `OK`, then move that data 1 step higher in the component/object/state level. The same would happen for every step. And at the end, a final validation before submitting either the edit or the create request to the server.

The problem is I have no idea how to do it. I am using React, Redux, RxJS and Redux Observables, to handle asynchronous data. For the wizard I have used both step-zilla and react-albus, but I don't mind making my own.

I am not expecting anyone to answer this, as I will not paste any code, as it does not make any sense. If you could create a sandbox with a simple example it would be great. Thank you and merry christmas...

Comment: Merry Xmas! I understand your problem, however, in Stack Overflow we target specific problems with specific solutions, not the broad problems like how to build an app. Try to reduce your problem into simple small problems, try few online solutions and then if stuck, then feel free to ask questions. We like to work with people who try to solve the problems themselves first. Show that you have tried to solve it. For more details on how to ask questions or which questions to ask, refer the FAQs https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Did you try doing it with render props. Try a library like formik. https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/overview